# Can't sign in in Xcode: "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application."

Tags: xcode, code-signing, xvim

I was trying to install Xvim2 in my XCode.

I ran the Xvim code sign tutorial - https://github.com/XVimProject/XVim2/blob/master/SIGNING_Xcode.md

After that I can not sign in to Xcode, I can not publish archives to test-flight.

Anytime I am trying to sign-in I am getting this error

**Can't sign in in Xcode: "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application."**

I searched everything and everywhere but can't found a solution.

Also checked that thread - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661221
But seems they don't have a solution also.

Any ideas, advice? Problem is very critical

Comment: What version of xcode and macos? I'm on Xcode(v: Version 12.3 ) Macos (Catalina - Intel) and have no issue building and signing XVim2 from the master branch and also publishing application archives to be verified

Comment: Before re-installing XCode I'd try 1) Clean rebuild & install of XVim2. 2) re-sign with your developer key, IE: `sudo codesign -f -s "Developer ID Application: {FirstName LastName} ({DEVELOPER ID})" /Applications/Xcode.app` 3) reboot  ...

Comment: My xcode is 12.3 also....

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while trying to notarize and "direct distribute" my own Mac App.

At first I assumed that Apple's Notary service was down, but their [Developer System Status page](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) showed that they were having no outages. The issue persisted for hours.

**Then I realized the problem: I needed to log in to [the Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/account) and accept their latest "program license aggreement".**

Just [log in](https://developer.apple.com/account) and you will likely see a large banner near near the top asking your to accept their latest agreement (see image below).

**NOTE:** Even after accepting their new license agreement, I was still experiencing the same issue. So I rebooted my Mac, rebuilt (aka re-"archived") my App again, and tried again. Then it worked.

[image]